# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the next/previous question buttons?

Tags: feature-request

I've just noticed the next/previous question buttons on the side of the question pages.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate between questions even quicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Go to `Edit Profile & Settings` > `Preferences` and enable `Keyboard shortcuts`. Then you can use Vi keys to navigate.

Comment: Awesome, there's a "new navigation" beta option in there too.

Comment: Have you got a quick summary of the Vi keys for we great unwashed?

Comment: Just hit `?` and you will get a list. Do it now :)

Comment: I've had to update this setting on MSO too. Is there a way to set it Network-wide, rather than per site?